# What's the keyword template mean in the function parameters

Tags: c++

The code like this

```
class A
{
public:
    typedef int C;
public:
    A()
    {

    }
    int x = 0;
};

void FuncA(A::template C a)
{
     std::cout << a;
}

void FuncB(A::C a)
{
     std::cout << a;
}

int main()
{
     FuncA(1);
     FuncB(1);
}
```

The code can successfully complie. When i run it, looks FuncA and FuncB has the same result.Whats' the difference between them.What's the template mean in FuncA.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know, they are the same thing.

Comment: Doesn't compile on GCC and clang https://godbolt.org/z/bf6jzdbhz

Comment: [The `template` disambiguator for dependent names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_template_disambiguator_for_dependent_names)